# Write factorial as imperative function using Haskell

Tags: haskell, continuations, monad-transformers

I have written the following code in Haskell:

```
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
fac n = do
          i<-newIORef 1
          f<-newIORef 1
          replicateM_ n $ do
            ri<-readIORef i
            modifyIORef f (\x->x*ri)
            modifyIORef i (+1)
          readIORef f
```

This is very nice code which implements factorial as an imperative function. But replicateM_ cannot fully simulate the use of a real for loop. So I tried to create something using continuations but I have failed here is my code:

```
ff = (`runContT` id) $ do
       callCC $ \exit1 -> do
         liftIO $ do
           i<-newIORef 1
           f<-newIORef 1
         callCC $ \exit2 -> do
           liftIO $ do 
             ri<-readIORef i
             modifyIORef (\x->x*ri)
             modifyIORef i (+1)
             rri<-readIORef i
             when (rri<=n) $ exit2(())
         liftIO $ do
           rf<-readIORef f
           return rf
```

Can you help me correct my code?
Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure: Are you an advanced user experimenting with IORefs and continuations or are you a beginning user who want advice on how to write a factorial function in an imperative style?

Comment: But... whyyyyy?

Comment: @kqr I am a beginner.

Comment: @DanielWagner when you write a program using the "for" statement in a imperative programming language, the compiler implements this using a conditional branch without increasing the code size of the block of code you wish to repeat. "replicateM" does the opposite it replicates the code many times increasing the code size. If I can write it using continuations I think that this will mimic the behavior (and the advantages) of the real "for" loop.

Comment: @Dragno When writing haskell write this, write your code declaratively and let GHC muck around with optimizations. If you want to mimic a for loop in Haskell, use tail calls.

Comment: You want `forM_` from `Control.Monad`.

Comment: @Dragno You have been misinformed. `replicateM` does not replicate code many times. Additionally, even your code using `replicateM` makes me wonder, "why?". Things can be so very much simpler if you allow them to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your a beginner to Haskell and not doing this simply to learn how continuations and IORefs work, you're doing it wrong.

The Haskell-y way to write an imperative loop is tail-calls or folds.

```
factorial n = foldl1' (*) [1..n]

factorial' n = go 1 n
   where go accum 0 = accum
         go accum n = go (n-1) (accum * n)
```

Also since Haskell's `callCC` in essence provides you an early return, using it to simulate loops is not going to work.

```
 callCC (\c -> ???)
```

Think about what we would have to put in for `???` in order to loop. somehow, we want to run `callCC` again if it returns a certain value, otherwise just keep going on our merry way.

But nothing we put in `???` can make the `callCC` run again! It's going to return a value no matter what we do. So instead we'll need to do something around that `callCC`

```
 let (continue, val) = callCC (someFunc val)
 in if continue
    then callCallCCAgain val
    else val
```

Something like this right? But wait, `callCallCCAgain` is recursion! It's even tail recursion! In fact, that `callCC` is doing no one any good

```
 loop val = let (continue, val') = doBody val
            in if continue
               then loop val'
               else val'
```

Look familiar? This is the same structure as `factorial'` above.

You can still use `IORef`s and something like the monad-loops package, but it's going to be an uphill battle always because Haskell isn't meant to be written like that.

#### Summary

When you want to directly do "loops" in haskell, use tail recursion. But really, try to use combinators like `fold` and `map`, they're like little specialized loops and GHC is fantastic at optimizing them. And definitely don't use `IORef`s, trying to program Haskell like it's C is just going to hurt your performance, readability, and everyone will be sad.